# Update Yandex coordinates through jquery

Tags: jquery, api, dictionary, yandex

I have no knowledge of jquery and I would like to change a Yandex map position.
The javascript function is as it follows:

```
    function fid_0000(ymaps) 
    {
         var map = new ymaps.Map("ymaps-map-id_0000", {center: [11.111111,22.222222], zoom: 17, type: "yandex#map"});
    };
```

and HTML is:

```
<div id="ymaps-map-id_0000" style="width: 450px; height: 450px;"></div>
```

How do I change its coordinates, possibly with a select tag, without reloading the page?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at the [Yandex API examples](http://api.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/examples/)

Particularly, look at the code example of [Changing the Map Center](http://api.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/examples/mappanto.html) would be most useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map.setCenter([lat, lng]);`